# Using Go and Revel, getting error c.RenderArgs is Undefined (possibly outdated?)

Tags: go, revel

I have a script that has some Go code with outdated revel. I ran into an issue that says:

```
 c.RenderArgs undefined (type *revel.Controller has no field or method RenderArgs)
```

And ive tried to search around, but can't figure out what to replace it with to fix the error. I'm not familiar with revel so its making things that much more difficult.

If someone could help, or simply link me to a space that could help(if i missed it, and i am sorry) i would be greatful!

Comment: Update your dependency?

Comment: Need more information. Post some code please.

Comment: @Tokoshiro if you have the latest Revel version, try changing `RenderArgs` to `ViewArgs`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ViewArgs` instead of `RenderArgs`.

Answer (score 0):

Without posting more of your code, your question cannot be accurately answered, but here is what I found in the [Godocs for Revel](https://godoc.org/github.com/robfig/revel#Controller.Render).

> func (c *Controller) Render(extraRenderArgs ...interface{}) Result
>
> Render a template corresponding to the calling Controller method. Arguments will be added to c.RenderArgs prior to rendering the template. They are keyed on their local identifier.

I believe your code is either trying to modify a field that was changed to be no longer exported, or calling a method that has been changed to the one above.

Comment: I think he's looking for this https://github.com/revel/revel/commit/a343bf7140d4f7059aebe0788c6d0e2c67e86295

Answer (score 0):

Tokoshiro

Please check your revel version and you project dependence revel version.
Due to revel v0.14.1 released, some variables name are changed.

Please check the release note. [revel v0.14.1 release note](https://github.com/revel/revel/releases/tag/v0.14.0)